# Pen input isn't correct working after 1709 Fall Creator Update

Tags: windows-10, input-device, microsoft-surface-pro-3, stylus

After the Windows 1709 Fall Creator Update the behavior of my surface pen has changed.

It seems that the Digital Pen input is interpreted as touch instead of mouse click.

I checked the battery of my pen, used Troubleshooting and refreshed the driver.
Nothing worked for me.

**Any ideas how to get the old behavior back without rollback?**

*If i press the button on my pen input will be recognized as mouse click again.*

---

According to the InterWebz this is a known and unhandled issue by Microsoft:

- [PocketNow Complain](http://pocketnow.com/2017/07/29/windows-10-fall-creators-update)
- [Microsoft Developer Board](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14277341/)